# I have not seen you in a while or I had not seen you in a while

Tags: grammar

If I last saw someone some time ago, and I am now meeting the person. Should the first sentence be either

> I have not seen you in a while.

or

> I had not seen you in a while.

I am leaning towards the first choice since I heard it more often and it just sounds familiar to me. However, I think that I am now seeing the person so I have now seen you. Therefore, should it be

> I had not seen you in a while

instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current meeting is in the present, so you would say "It's nice to see you, because I have not seen you in a while."

At the end of the meeting it becomes in the past, so you can say "Goodbye, it was nice to see you, because I had not seen you in a while."

You could also refer to a previous meeting. "Do you remember meeting in Paris? I had not seen you in a while."